# Multer: path of the file isn't right

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I added multer to my node js app and it works fine, just the path of the image which I need to store in db isn't correct. Can't find the problem, its obviously some stupid mistake made by me.

This is my setup for multer

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public/images',
  filename: function(req, file, next){
      next(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage});
```

Here is how I use it to store the path

```
router.post('/add', upload.single('myImage'), function(req, res){
  req.checkBody('title','Title is required').notEmpty();
  //req.checkBody('author','Author is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('body','Body is required').notEmpty();

  // Get Errors
  let errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    res.render('add_article', {
      title:'Add Article',
      errors:errors
    });
  } else {
    let article = new Article();
    //var date = new Date();
    article.title = req.body.title;
    article.author = req.user._id;
    article.body = req.body.body;
    article.descript = req.body.descript;
    article.category = req.body.category;  
    article.date = getDate();
    article.time = getTime();
    article.comments = 0;   
    article.img = req.file.path;   
    console.log(req.file);
    article.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
      } else {
        req.flash('success','Article Added');
        res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

You can see from here that the path isnt right and I can't use it on GET

```
{ _id: 5bd993756373a5182460aa2a,
  title: 'Sport 5',
  author: '5acab056708e0d1248cba6ed',
  body: 'sadddddddddddddd213',
  descript: 'dsadas',
  category: 'sport',
  date: '2018/10/31',
  time: '12:35',
  comments: 0,
  img: 'public\\images\\1540985717747-nike_logo_slogan_sport_advertising_42643_1280x1024.jpg',
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: What is not correct with the path? That it starts with `public/images` that it has  ```\\``` instead of ```/```?  You always need to explain what the expected result should be. Because the path in `img` looks correct to me.

Comment: Expected result should be slashes not backslashes in order to use path. Because with backslashes in path I cant GET the image.. Or I just don't know how to get it?

Comment: `img` contains the file system path so if you are on windows then it is ```\\``` you need to convert the filesystem path to a url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multer is working correctly on your end you just need to convert the system path into a url accessible one.

Here this will help you.

```
article.comments = 0;
let fileUrl = req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/").substring("public".length);
article.img = fileUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens in windows because any file path in windows has back slash only but to make the file accessible through url it has to have front slash. So just use the below code to convert all backslash to front slash

const imageUrl = req.file.path.replace("\", "/");